# php-fpm not scaling as well as php-fastcgi

Tags: nginx, apc, php

I'm trying to optimize a PHP site to scale under high loads.
I'm currently using Nginx, APC and also Redis as a database cache.

All that works well and scales much better than stock.

**My question is in regard to php-fpm**:

I load tested using php-fpm VS php-fastcgi, in theory I should use php-fpm as it has better process handling and also should play better with APC since php-fastcgi processes can't share the same APC cache, and use more memory, if I understand it right.

Now the thing is under a heavy load test, php-fastcgi performed better, it's not faster but it "holds" longer, whereas php-fpm started giving timeouts and errors much sooner.

Does that make any sense ?

Probably I just have not configured php-fpm optimally maybe, but I tried a variety of settings and could not match php-fastcgi under that high volume load test scenario.

Any recommendations / comments / best practices / settings to try would be appreciated.

Thanks.

I mostly messed with the number of servers:

```
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 100
pm.max_requests = 5000
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64)

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted your FPM Pool Configuration(s)

Comment: Are you using static, dynamic, or ondemand?

Comment: I am using dynamic, sorry I forgot to mention that. After more testing I found out that fpm performs OK until cpu starvation, it seems fcgi handles that better but I suppose it's a bit of an edge case. I've tested with a "high CPU" instance(AWS EC2) and that helped quite a bit.

Comment: Also waned to note that I did better with 10 | 5 | 30 for start|min|max servers .... higher did not help as CPU was already saturated at that point.

Comment: Yeah those settings are going to be different for everyone. They are based on the machine you are running and can be difficult to find the right combination that works for you. I'm curious if you have tried to use the ondemand feature? This way no CPU usages is spooled up that isn't being used. It's only spooled when it's needed.

Comment: No I haven't yet, I'll try that too. Thanks.